# OR notation and bit shift why = sign why 1

Tags: c

I am new to C.  Can someone tell me what is happening with these instructions which are from sample code setting up timer interrupts in an Atmel in an Arduino

```
  TCCR2A |= (1 << WGM21);
  // Set CS21 bit for 8 prescaler
  TCCR2B |= (1 << CS21);   
  // enable timer compare interrupt
  TIMSK2 |= (1 << OCIE2A);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`TCCR2A` is a register. Something like `00100001`.
`WGM21` is a number. For example 3.

`(1 << WGM21)` this shifts a 1 for 3(`WGM21`) positions left.
So this results is `00000100`.

So now we have: `TCCR2A |= 00000100;`
which results in: `TCCR2A = TCCR2A | 00000100;`

if the actual state of `TCCR2A` is `00100001` 
 
it looks like this: `TCCR2A = 00100001 | 00000100;`

Now the answer is `TCCR2A = 00100101;`

Comment: thanks. that is what I was missing